# EDIFACT message parser

Tags: c#, edifact

I have the following example EDIFACT with two messages within an interchange.

`UNA:+.? 'UNB+IATB:1+6XPPC+LHPPC+940101:0950+1'UNH+1+PAORES:93:1:IA'MSG+1:45'IFT+3+XYZCOMPANY AVAILABILITY'ERC+A7V:1:AMD'IFT+3+NO MORE FLIGHTS'
ODI'TVL+240493:1000::1220+FRA+JFK+DL+400+C'PDI++C:3+Y::3+F::1'APD+74C:0:::6++++++6X'TVL+240493:1740::2030+JFK+MIA+DL+081+C'PDI++C:4'APD+EM2:0:1630::6+++++++DA'
UNT+13+1'UNH+2+PAORES:93:1:IA'MSG+1:45'IFT+3+XYZCOMPANY AVAILABILITY'ERC+A7V:1:AMD'IFT+3+NO MORE FLIGHTS'ODI'TVL+240493:1000::1220+FRA+JFK+DL+400+C'
PDI++C:3+Y::3+F::1'APD+74C:0:::6++++++6X'TVL+240493:1740::2030+JFK+MIA+DL+081+C'PDI++C:4'APD+EM2:0:1630::6+++++++DA'UNT+13+2'UNZ+1+1`

I understand that an interchange denoted by `UNB..UNZ` service segments can hold multiple messages.  As an example I have included two messages here as you can see.

Before I design the rules for my parser, is this message a valid message to start with?  I have tried a free EDI viewer from Sourceforge, but it seems to warn it's not valid so I don't know how accurate the tool is.  There are no other free EDI validator tools that I know of that I can use to check the accuracy of EDIFACT messages that I am generating using my own API I have developed in C#.

Answer (score 0):

A small point, but if you had replaced the segment delimiter (') with ' Line Feeds in any text editor these type of count mismatches would have been much easier to see at first glance.

```
UNA:+.? '
UNB+IATB:1+6XPPC+LHPPC+940101:0950+1'
UNH+1+PAORES:93:1:IA'
MSG+1:45'
IFT+3+XYZCOMPANY AVAILABILITY'
ERC+A7V:1:AMD'
IFT+3+NO MORE FLIGHTS'
ODI'
TVL+240493:1000::1220+FRA+JFK+DL+400+C'
PDI++C:3+Y::3+F::1'
APD+74C:0:::6++++++6X'
TVL+240493:1740::2030+JFK+MIA+DL+081+C'
PDI++C:4'
APD+EM2:0:1630::6+++++++DA'
UNT+13+1'

UNH+2+PAORES:93:1:IA'
MSG+1:45'
IFT+3+XYZCOMPANY AVAILABILITY'
ERC+A7V:1:AMD'
IFT+3+NO MORE FLIGHTS'
ODI'
TVL+240493:1000::1220+FRA+JFK+DL+400+C'
PDI++C:3+Y::3+F::1'
APD+74C:0:::6++++++6X'
TVL+240493:1740::2030+JFK+MIA+DL+081+C'
PDI++C:4'
APD+EM2:0:1630::6+++++++DA'
UNT+13+2'
UNZ+2+1
```

Answer (score -1):

I have figured it out.  I made a mistake in forgetting to set the `UNZ` control count to `2` to reflect there are 2 messages in the interchange.

The correct message is:

`UNA:+.? 'UNB+IATB:1+6XPPC+LHPPC+940101:0950+1'UNH+1+PAORES:93:1:IA'MSG+1:45'IFT+3+XYZCOMPANY AVAILABILITY'ERC+A7V:1:AMD'IFT+3+NO MORE FLIGHTS'
ODI'TVL+240493:1000::1220+FRA+JFK+DL+400+C'PDI++C:3+Y::3+F::1'APD+74C:0:::6++++++6X'TVL+240493:1740::2030+JFK+MIA+DL+081+C'PDI++C:4'APD+EM2:0:1630::6+++++++DA'
UNT+13+1'UNH+2+PAORES:93:1:IA'MSG+1:45'IFT+3+XYZCOMPANY AVAILABILITY'ERC+A7V:1:AMD'IFT+3+NO MORE FLIGHTS'ODI'TVL+240493:1000::1220+FRA+JFK+DL+400+C'
PDI++C:3+Y::3+F::1'APD+74C:0:::6++++++6X'TVL+240493:1740::2030+JFK+MIA+DL+081+C'PDI++C:4'APD+EM2:0:1630::6+++++++DA'UNT+13+2'UNZ+2+1`

This now validates using [EDIFACT Viewer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/edifactviewer/).

Comment: @Fandango68: there was an English version available when I first downloaded it 4 years ago.